# Navigation Between tableView to detailedTableView through XIB file

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a tableView. In that on clicking on a particular row I want to send some data to another `XIB` file through `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

At present I am able to navigate between the XIB via this

```
 abc *vc = [[abc alloc] init];

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

but havent achieved data passing yet. Can somebody help ?

Comment: If you want to send string  to abc class, add property NSString *detail; in abc class and set the value in your class after abc *vc = [[abc alloc] init]; vc.detail = @"";

Comment: not working.. the string detail shows empty

Answer (score 0):

Add a property of type string in abc class as below :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *passedString;
```

In your code after initialisation of the viewcontrller object pass the details to the property as below :

```
 abc *vc = [[abc alloc] init];
 vc. passedString = @"Pass The String Value Here."   //If you pass empty string it would show the empty sting in abc ViewController
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Hope this helps.